# A sample guava cache application with maven

Tags: spring, caching, maven, guava

Is there a sample application that is developed by using guava cache application and maven. I need to have an explanation to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a related post in http://www.yusufaytas.com/caching-guava/. It tells the basic features about guava caching. At the end of the post, it also gives the source code.

Comment: Thank you very much. What does callable classes do?

Comment: Callable classes are interfaces that provides substitution mechanism for standard load operation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example http://syntx.co/languages-frameworks/java/implementing-google-guava-cache-using-proxy-pattern/ which shows how to use google guava cache while implementing a proxy design pattern. The post also lists maven dependencies for guava cache.